# How to prevent anyPicker from taking user minutes?

Tags: javascript, time

I work on date time with a theme like IOS time picker.
so I use [AnyPicker](https://github.com/nehakadam/AnyPicker)

My problem is when choosing the hour, and not touch minutes, and then click ok, the minutes set automatically based on users minutes PC.

How to prevent that?

this is my code:

```
$("#start-time").AnyPicker({
        mode: "datetime",
        dateTimeFormat: "H:mm",
        intervals: { h: 1, m: 30 },
        layout: "fixed",
        headerTitle: {},
        onChange: function(iRow, iComp, oSelectedValues) {
            console.log("Changed Value : " + iRow + " " + iComp + " " + oSelectedValues);
        },
        i18n:
        {
            setButton: "OK",
            cancelButton: "",
        },
        theme: "iOS" // "Default", "iOS", "Android", "Windows"
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After research and testing about this issue, I found a solution, I check this code and modify the code from anypicker.js.
[image]

and then I modify this point `dInput.getMinutes()`
first I check current minutes and use this to check if `dInput.getMinutes()` same current minutes. if same I set to `00` if not same get minutes from `dInput.getMinutes()`.